# Standard Half-Cell Reduction Potential for Periodate to Iodine

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reduction-potential

I'm looking for standard half-cell reduction potential $\ce{IO4-}$/$\ce{I2}$ in acid medium. Unfortunately I was unable to find the value in all comprehensible reference books. Hard to believe this values have not been measured or calculated so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the standard half-cell reduction potential $\ce{IO4^{−}/I2}$ in acid medium depicted using Latimer diagram.

[image]

([source](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4Ka5HSSrR_yeENFS0hvbjdUR00/view?pref=2&pli=1))

Note: Here $\ce{IO4-}$ (periodate ion) gets hydrated to form orthoperiodic acid which is $\ce{HIO4.2H2O}$  or $\ce{H5IO6}$.